# Python Selenium webdriver slow typing

Tags: python, internet-explorer, python-2.7, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I am using Selenium with the 32 bit IE driver and have been experiencing very slow typing. I have done a lot of reading on the subject and have found that the solution is to use the 32 bit driver with the 32 bit version if IE. I have heard that 32 bit IE is the default that is used, however when I use my script to open IE and look at the processes list in windows, it appears that there is both a 64 and 32 version opened. Ending the task of the 32 bit will cause the IE window to show an error, while ending the 64 bit process will close the IE window. What can I do to make sure I have the right version of IE and that I don't have to deal with this slow typing.

Comment: Are you using 32bit Python? Use task manager to find out, notice task manager shows *32 on processes like on this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28896522/selenium-send-keys-slow-in-ie9-10-11-windows-7-64bit-32bit-ieserver

Comment: I have tried all combinations of 32 bit and 64 bit Python and Selenium.

Comment: Could be the same issue as http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28896522/selenium-send-keys-slow-in-ie9-10-11-windows-7-64bit-32bit-ieserver

Comment: I found Antivirus was the cause of slow typing in my case rather than the IE version. See the post above.