# Selenium Send Keys Slow in IE9/10/11 Windows 7 64Bit (32bit IEServer)

Tags: python, internet-explorer, selenium, nosetests

Running Selenium Tests via Python 2.7.9 or C# app I'm getting really slow character input into text fields. Elsewhere I have seen the fix of using the 32bit IEDriver.exe but this hasn't fixed the issue for me. I've also tried with 'protected mode' all set to on and off. As you can see in the image below, all related processes are all in 32bit mode on this box. Has anyone fixed this please?

**Versions:** Python 2.7.9, nose 1.3.4, selenium 2.45.0, IEDriver 2.35.3.0, Internet Explorer 9.0.8112.16421

[image: Task Manager]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check your antivirus. I had McAffee preventing IEDriverServer.exe from using hooks which made SendKeys painfully slow.

Comment: I had McAfee running, I disabled it and it worked! Thank-you.

Answer (score 0):

I got a selenium send keys slow issue in remote machine.When space is low. Try deleting unwanted logs and give a try it will speed up send keys.